# htaccess clean url with multiple parameters not working correctly?

Tags: php, .htaccess

the htaccess for my clean url with multiple parameters is not working correctly.

when you goto the page: `/template?shopname=streamer&id=1` with the full url, the page/images/includes work properly.

[image]

But when you goto the page with the clean url: `/details/streamer/1`

[image]

it doesn't load all the content, images are missing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^details/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)$ template?shopname=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

And this is the code at the top of the template file:

```
<?php
include_once "functions.php";
$shopname = $_GET['shopname'];
$shop = template($shopname);
$title = $shop['title']." | DreamRJ";
$descr = $shop['descr'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
include "header.php";
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you're including images with a relative path? Masking the URL the way you do breaks those so you need to set absolute paths for your images and other client side resources.

Comment: lol oops hahahaha, yeah my stupid mistake, totally forgot about that i used ../img/etcetcetcblahblah in the database image path. fixed it now, thanks for reminding me and for the help :)